# Reflection with LINQ without for or foreach

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

I'm trying to filter a list of objects based on specific properties via reflection. The problem is I can't find a way to do it without a for or foreach loop. Not that there's anything wrong with that, but I'd like to use LINQ to capture the object I'm filtering for instead.

```
string prop = 'SortOrder';
string propVal = '1';
PropertyInfo result;
//StackObject is passed in and can contain over a million objects
var objList = (StackObject as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList();

foreach (var obj in objList)
{
    PropertyInfo filterProperty = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop);

    if (filterProperty.GetValue(obj, null).ToString() == propVal)
    {
        result = (PropertyInfo)obj;
        return result;
    }
}
```

I have tried this:

```
var objList = (StackObject as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToList();
PropertyInfo desiredObject = (PropertyInfo)objList.Where(o => o.GetType().GetProperty(prop).GetValue(o, null).ToString() == propVal);
```

But I keep getting a list of objects or null instead of the specific object. The end goal is to be more performant (as the list of objects can grow quite large at times) and filter appropriately for a given property.

Comment: Do you want all `PropertyInfo`s that that meet the criteria, or just the first one?

Comment: @JonathonChase So far I have only needed the one, and that's all the foreach has returned, but either would work.

Comment: did you check what the ToString() returns?   Normally it will return System in the name which will not match.  I have done similar code a few times in the last week with linq.  You need to compare a Type with a Type (not the string).  So you need to use typeof(and type here).

Comment: @jdweng why would I compare the type of an object to that of a string variable? I'm not following, because that appears to leave out the value I'm trying to compare on.

Comment: You have following : GetValue(o, null).ToString().  Don't you want in the where "Type == Type", then when you get the object extract the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use `Select` to get your initial property info along with the object. You can then filter to all of the matches with `Where`, or to the first match with `FirstOrDefault`.

Something like this should work:

```
var result = (StackObject as IEnumerable)
    .Cast<object>()
    .Select(obj => (Obj: obj, Prop: obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop)))
    .FirstOrDefault(tup => tup.Prop?.GetValue(tup.Obj, null)?.ToString() == propVal)
    ?.Prop;
```

This is utilizing a tuple of the object and the property within the select syntax so that your later filtering has access to both. The same predicate in the `FirstOrDefault` should work for a `Where` should you want to get all matches.

As an alternative to tuples, you could use an anonymous object. With an anonymous object, you may get something like this:

```
var result = (StackObject as IEnumerable)
    .Cast<object>()
    .Select(obj => new { Obj = obj, Prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop)} )
    .FirstOrDefault(item => item.Prop?.GetValue(item.Obj, null)?.ToString() == propVal)
    ?.Prop;
```

If you wanted to use `Where`, you would need an additional `Select` to get the `item => item.Prop` values from the filtered enumerable.

Comment: I'm going to agree with that "use anonymous types", or at least _named_ tuples.

Comment: @gunr2171 As far as I know, there isn't a way to deconstruct tuples within a lambda expression, or that would likely be my preferred route. If that's not correct, let me know.

Comment: That's a good point. I don't think that's possible at the moment, best you could do is `Select(obj => (Obj: obj, Prop: ...)` and `tup.Obj...tup.Prop`.

Comment: @gunr2171 I wasn't familiar with that aspect of named tuples, thanks I'll edit accordingly.